# Ubuntu Freezes, but audio still works

Tags: 22.04, freeze

I'm Using Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS and my system occasionally freezes.
The Screen does not update, the keyboard does not seem to do anything and the power button does nothing, I can only Reisub.

The only thing still working is audio, be it Telegram notifications or a Video.

Sometimes waiting long enough makes the screen black and forcefully logs me off, I can use the OS normally after that.

This problem is also on my secondary pc.

Last time this happend I had the system monitor on, and I saw that cpu4 was on 100% and the others where below 50%m but I don't know if this relates to this problem.

Sone more info on my pc:
16 GB RAM
Hardware Model: BIOSTAR Group A10N-9830E
Processor: AMD fx9830p radeon r7,  12 compute cores 4c+8g*4
Graphics: CARRIZO (carrizo, LLVM 15.0.6, DRM 3.49, 6.2.0-32-generic)
Gnome version: 42.5
Windowing system: Wayland

I have 2047 mb swap

Comment: Do you have swap space? Do: `free -m`. Please [edit] your question to add whatever information you get. Do not use Add Comment.